# Python script is not executed from PHP script on local server

Tags: php, python, xampp

I am using PHP and `XAMPP`. I have enabled port `localhost:8080` and I want to execute a python script (`Main.py`) from my PHP script (`index.php`). My PHP script is located at:

`/Users/User/.bitnami/stackman/machines/xampp/volumes/root/htdocs/index.php`

and the Python script is located at:

`/Users/User/.bitnami/stackman/machines/xampp/volumes/root/htdocs/Main.py`.

My Python script is the following:

```
print('Hello World')
```

My PHP script is the following:

```
<?php

$output = exec('/usr/local/bin/python3 /Users/User/.bitnami/stackman/machines/xampp/volumes/root/htdocs/Main.py ' . ' 2>&1');
var_dump($output);

?>
```

(/`usr/local/bin/python3` is the output of `which python3` at the terminal)

However, the output that I am getting at `localhost:8080` is:

```
string(40) "sh: 1: /usr/local/bin/python3: not found"
```

I have also tested different variations of my line with `exec()` by writing for example `exec('/Users/User/.bitnami/stackman/machines/xampp/volumes/root/htdocs/Main.py ' . ' 2>&1')` but nothing returns the right output.

**What am I doing wrong and how can I fix it?**

I am aware of similar posts on StackOverflow ([Running a Python script from PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19735250/running-a-python-script-from-php?utm_medium=organic&utm_source=google_rich_qa&utm_campaign=google_rich_qa), [Can't execute Python script from PHP document](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32598420/cant-execute-python-script-from-php-document), [Python Script Failing to Execute from PHP exec()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15594946/python-script-failing-to-execute-from-php-exec), [How to properly call Python 3 script from PHP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34957283/how-to-properly-call-python-3-script-from-php)) but none of this works as such for me.

I am wondering if my problem is related to the fact that I did not make any configuration to run the Python script on `XAMPP`  as it is described at some posts here ([Running Python scripts with Xampp](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42704846/running-python-scripts-with-xampp?noredirect=1&lq=1)).

Comment: Can you start python3 in the terminal by typing /usr/local/bin/python3 ?

Comment: Thank you for your comment. I think that I do since I get the following output when I enter it: `Python 3.6.3 (v3.6.3:2c5fed86e0, Oct  3 2017, 00:32:08) 
[GCC 4.2.1 (Apple Inc. build 5666) (dot 3)] on darwin
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.`

Comment: did you put `#!/usr/bin/env python` at the start of your python script?

Comment: So your path to python3 is correct. I use exactly the same setup as you (MacOSX, XAMPP, Python3, PHP) and I do get the desired output when running your code. When I change the directory of python3 "$output = exec('/usr/local/bin/python3...)" to "($output = exec('/usr/local/bin/python...), which does not exist, I get the following error message: string(52) "sh: /usr/local/bin/python: No such file or directory" - so string(52) instead of string(40). There must be some problem with XAMPP config I guess.

Comment: Can you try to use localhost/ instead of localhost:8080/ - and run your php script as follows: localhost/Main.py